# Combine two tables and echo out the result (PHP MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables; 'client' and 'sys_notes' in the same DB.
(`SELECT client.*, sys_notes.* FROM client LEFT JOIN sys_notes ON sys_notes.client_id = client.id ORDER BY create_date DESC`)

I need to combine the two tables echo in the same `<div>content</div>`, like this:

echo all from client = first.name + last.name (e.g. Scott)
echo all from client = role
echo all from client = whatever else
echo all from sys_notes sent by Robert Scott = note1, note2, note3, note(etc.)...
echo all from client = whatever else
echo all from client = whatever else

example output:

---

```
<div class="content">
```

Robert Scott
*Supervisor*
Robert works at the order office at the firm.
Robert´s notes:

- today: (Note from sys_notes table)
- yesterday: (Note from sys_notes table)
- 19.oct 2013: (Note from sys_notes table)

Robert´s Phone: 000 000 000
Robert´s E-mail: etc.
Other information about Robert: ............

```
</div>
```

---

```
<div class="content">
```

Lisa Johansson
*Supervisor*
Lisa works at the marketing dep.
Lisas´s notes:

- today: (Note from sys_notes table)
- 12.may 2013: (Note from sys_notes table)

Lisa´s Phone: 000 000 000
Lisa´s E-mail: etc.
Other information about Lisa: ............

```
</div>
```

---

**When i echo results today Robert is being "echoed" as many times he has notes,
 with one note in each `<div class="content">`. (In example over Robert has 3 notes & 3 different Robert-div is echoed.)**

Please help.

--- UPDATE ---

```
-- Table structure for table `sys_notes`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sys_notes` (
  `note_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `note_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `owning_user` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `note` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`note_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

-- Table structure for table `client`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `issue` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `other` longtext NOT NULL,
  `owning_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1081 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
```

instead of:

```
SELECT
```

or GROUP BY statement.

-- EDIT --

Example echo:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT client.*, GROUP_CONCAT(sys_notes.note SEPARATOR "|") as note, sys_notes.* FROM client LEFT JOIN sys_notes ON sys_notes.client_id = client.id GROUP BY sys_notes.client_id ORDER BY create_date DESC");

ob_start();
?>

<div class="content">

<?php
foreach($result as $row) {

    sprintf("<p>%s %s<br />%s<br />%s</p> %s <ul>", $row['firstname'], $row['lastname'], $row['role'], $row['desc'](example));

    foreach(explode("|", $row['note']) as $note) {
        sprintf("<li>%s</li>", $note);
    }

    sprintf("</ul>");
}
?>
</div>
<?

$result = ob_end_clean();

echo $result;
```

-- FINAL UPDATE --

```
<?php

try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$result = $db->query('SELECT client . * , GROUP_CONCAT( sys_notes.note SEPARATOR  "|" ) AS n, sys_notes.* 
FROM client
LEFT JOIN sys_notes ON sys_notes.client_id = client.id
GROUP BY sys_notes.client_id
ORDER BY create_date DESC');

ob_start();
?>

<div class="content">

<?php

foreach($result as $row) {

    printf("<p>%s %s<br />%s</p> %s <ul>", $row['first_name'], $row['last_name'], $row['issue'], $row['other']);

    foreach(explode("|", $row['n']) as $note) {
        printf("<li>%s</li>", $note);
    }

    printf("</ul>");
}
?>
</div>
<?php

ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more? How would i then echo it out to get the result as described over?

Comment: Just loop the result and echo certain rows like echo $row['note'];

Comment: hi, i´ve studying your suggestion and I understand what we are doing, at least thats good! =). I´ve tried this, but the output is only "1". Literally just: 1 (which is the first id (AI) in sys_notes...). Can you help me a bit more, i really appreciate your helping out here - thanks!

Comment: Could u post somewhere the db structure and your code? Pastebin would be nice :)

Comment: Yeah Stupid mistake. You should use printf instead of sprintf :) I had my mind somewhere else i guess... I'll post a new code under --UPDATE-- section in second.

Comment: Although you definitely shouldnt join cells like this. You should just get all values, check if the user is same as row before and just output another node.

Comment: Ok, get it - works really good! Learning a lot - Thank you very much! When it comes to your last comment, (I'm happy with the output, but as you say): "you shouldn't join cells like this....". What solution would suggest to do instead?

Comment: Sorry for so long reply - i wasn't here for 2 days. I think that you should jest get all rows without group by and group_concat statement, order them by client.id and after that in PHP loop just check if the previous row had same client as current one.

Also, please accept my solution if it works :) It'd be nice to get some reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

```
1.Make Array
2.you use while loop for iterating complete if first+lastname is same then use same array index 
3. within loop make array like $a['notes'][]=$row['NOTES'];
```

then echo above array

Comment: Ok following, but can you give me the example (3.) of the array and "then echo above array"?